# Get an array of X's from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using JavaScript, what is the best way to get a list of all the X's from a multi-dim array and place in a new array?  I want to use either reduce or map if possible?  Is there a term for this process that I should be aware of like a math process?

`[{x:0,y:8,z:-1}, {x:1, y:8.5, z:-0.5}, {x:2, y:9, z:0}]`

and adding this very late (prefer a solution using this if possible):

`[[0,8,-1], [1, 8.5, -0.5], [2, 9, 0]]`

How do I get just the x's:

```
[0,1,2]
```

Comment: ahh thanks.  fixing it now

Comment: `console.log([{x:0,y:8,z:-1}, {x:1, y:8.5, z:-0.5}, {x:2, y:9, z:0}].map(e => e.x));`

Comment: Is that JavaScript?

Comment: yes it is `:)`.

Comment: @NenadVracar Clever, but your code will fail if we replace even one 'x' with every other letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Maybe not that smart, but I'm sure you can understand an every line of that script.

```js
var arr = [{x:0,y:8,z:-1}, {x:1, y:8.5, z:-0.5}, {x:2, y:9, z:0}];
var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var key in arr[i]) {
      array.push(arr[i][key]);
      break;
    }
  }
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This returns the first key, which is not necessarily `x` (consider `[...{y:5,x:1}...`)

Comment: And objects do not guarantee order of property and your code takes first property from each object.

Comment: Agreed. I think he should precise it. Because only 'X' can be understood in two ways. First, he wants only 'X's, and the second way - he want's only the first key value from each object. @georg

Comment: I should have used array of arrays to be more precise like this: [[x:0,8,-1], [1, 8.5,-0.5], [2, 9,0]]  ... I started using the {} and got off track.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var points = [[0,8,-1], [1, 8.5, -0.5], [2, 9, 0]];
    var abscissas = points.reduce( (a,v)=> {a.push(v[0]); return a}, []);
    // abscissas array is now [0,1,2]
```

processes each entry in the `points` array using `reduce` (as requested) pushing points' x-ordinates (`v[0]`) onto the accumulation array passed as the previous value.

There must be many ways of doing this and using `Array.prototype.map` is simpler than using `reduce`:

```
    var abscissas = points.map( (v)=>v[0])
```

I would call the mathematical process "projection onto the x axis" but a mathematician might differ.

Comment: Ah, looked it up and projection using [[1],[1],[1]] multiplication is probably not possible in JavaScript I'm guessing.